# ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I'm trying to use a sigmoid to join the output of two models with different embedding matrix. but I keep getting the error at the concatenate line. I have tried other suggestions from similar questions but it keeps giving the same error. I feel I'm missing something but I can't find it. please help explain. Thanks

```
############################            MODEL   1      ######################################
input_tensor=Input(shape=(35,))
input_layer= Embedding(vocab_size, 300, input_length=35, weights=[embedding_matrix],trainable=True)(input_tensor)
conv_blocks = []
filter_sizes = (2,3,4)
for fx in filter_sizes:
    conv_layer= Conv1D(100, kernel_size=fx, activation='relu', data_format='channels_first')(input_layer)   #filters=100, kernel_size=3
    maxpool_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4)(conv_layer)
    flat_layer= Flatten()(maxpool_layer)
    conv_blocks.append(flat_layer)
conc_layer=concatenate(conv_blocks, axis=1)
graph = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=conc_layer)
model = Sequential()
model.add(graph)
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

############################            MODEL    2     ######################################
input_tensor_1=Input(shape=(35,))
input_layer_1= Embedding(vocab_size, 300, input_length=35, weights=[embedding_matrix_1],trainable=True)(input_tensor_1)
conv_blocks_1 = []
filter_sizes_1 = (2,3,4)
for fx in filter_sizes_1:
    conv_layer_1= Conv1D(100, kernel_size=fx, activation='relu', data_format='channels_first')(input_layer_1)   #filters=100, kernel_size=3
    maxpool_layer_1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4)(conv_layer_1)
    flat_layer_1= Flatten()(maxpool_layer_1)
    conv_blocks_1.append(flat_layer_1)
conc_layer_1=concatenate(conv_blocks_1, axis=1)
graph_1 = Model(inputs=input_tensor_1, outputs=conc_layer_1)
model_1 = Sequential()
model_1.add(graph_1)
model_1.add(Dropout(0.2))


fused = concatenate([graph, graph_1], axis=-1)
prediction = Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(fused)
model = Model(inputs=[input_tensor,input_tensor_1], outputs=[prediction])
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='Adagrad', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

This is the error  trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DL_Ensemble.py", line 145, in <module>
    fused = concatenate([graph, graph_1], axis= 1 )
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
   packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/merge.py", line 705, in concatenate
    return Concatenate(axis=axis, **kwargs)(inputs)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 887, in __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2141, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)
   File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
   packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py", line 306, in wrapper
output_shape = fn(instance, input_shape)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
   packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/merge.py", line 378, in build
    raise ValueError('A `Concatenate` layer should be called '
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs
```

UPDATE: I have reflected the answers given by @VivekMehta, however, I have this error.

`File "DL_Ensemble.py", line 165, in <module>
        model.fit([train_sequences,train_sequences], train_y, epochs=10, 
    verbose=False, batch_size=32, class_weight={0: 6.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0})
    File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
       packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 709, in fit
        return func.fit(
    File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
       packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 313, in fit
        training_result = run_one_epoch(
    File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
       packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 123, in run_one_epoch
        batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
       File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
       packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py", 
    line 
        86, in execution_function
            distributed_function(input_fn))
     File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
       packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 457, in __call__
        result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
     File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
       packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 520, in _call
        return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
     File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
       packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1823, in __call__
            return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: 
    disable=protected-access
    File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
       packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1137, in _filtered_call
        return self._call_flat(
    File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
       packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1223, in _call_flat
    flat_outputs = forward_function.call(
    File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
       packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 506, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
    File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
       packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
    File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:

    Conv2DCustomBackpropInputOp only supports NHWC.
         [[node Conv2DBackpropInput (defined at /usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_2250]`

```
Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

I also wanted to add that when the code is run on a GPU as opposed to a CPU, the error occurs on the same line as before but the message changes to :

```
File "DL_Ensemble.py", line 166, in <module>
model.fit([train_sequences,train_sequences], train_y, epochs=10, verbose=False, batch_size=32, class_weight={0: 6.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0})
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 880, in fit
validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 329, in model_iteration
batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3073, in __call__
self._make_callable(feed_arrays, feed_symbols, symbol_vals, session)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3019, in _make_callable
callable_fn = session._make_callable_from_options(callable_opts)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1471, in _make_callable_from_options
return BaseSession._Callable(self, callable_options)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1425, in __init__
session._session, options_ptr, status)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Conv2DCustomBackpropInputOp only supports NHWC.
     [[{{node training/Adagrad/gradients/conv1d_5/conv1d/Conv2D_grad/Conv2DBackpropInput}}]]
Exception ignored in: <function BaseSession._Callable.__del__ at 0x7fe4dd06a730>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1455, in __del__
self._session._session, self._handle, status)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No such callable handle: 94697914208640
```

Comment: you are using `concatenate` at multiple places. Please post full error trace so it becomes more clear which part is causing error.

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: @VivekMehta I have posted it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So from you stack trace, code is throwing error at:

```
fused = concatenate([graph, graph_1], axis= 1 )
print(type(graph))
# output: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model'>
```

This error is coming because [`concatenate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate?version=stable) expects list of tensors to be concatenated. While you are passing `graph` and `graph_1` which is not tensor but a [`Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=stable) instance.

So from your code I assume that you want to `concatenate` output of these two models. In that case you'll have to change above line to:

```
fused = concatenate([graph.outputs[0], graph_1.outputs[0]], axis=-1)
```

Here, `graph.outputs` gives list of outputs by given by Model. Since each model is giving us one output, we will take 0th index from each output.

Change this part and you'll get model summary as you are expecting.

Comment: Oh thank you. The model summary is generating well. Please, can you point me to something that would explain this concept? I would never have guessed it. Also, when i tried to fit the model, I got this error `ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 array:`. it has to do with my train set. I have confirmed it is a numpy array but still same error. The other similar questions have no answers. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Also, the model fits correctly when I'm using just one model.

Comment: I have attached documentation links for `concatenate` and `Model` in the answer. You can check input expected by method.

Comment: *For your error*: your model expects two inputs as defined here `Model(inputs=[input_tensor,input_tensor_1], outputs=[prediction])`. So you'll have to pass list of two inputs as per shape defined in `input_tensor` and `input_tensor_1`

Comment: I did that previously and it didn't solve the problem `model.fit([train_sequences,train_sequences], train_y, epochs=10, verbose=False, batch_size=100`

Comment: What is shape of `train_sequences` and `train_y`?

Comment: Their shapes are correct. `(18587, 35) ` and `(18587,)` respectively. Sorry I forgot to mention that the error message changed to `Function call stack:distributed_function` after your suggestion to pass a list of two input. Still trying read what it means

Comment: It will become difficult to debug without full error trace, feel free to edit your original question or posting as new question.

Comment: @Kosi  It has something to do with `channels_first` in `Conv1D`, since removing it works perfectly. But weather it should be done or not depends on how and what data you are passing. If you still face any problem I would suggest to put that as new question, since it is different from original one.

Comment: Thank you @Vivek, it's working now. How did you figure that out? Experience? or was it clear from the Traceback? Was at it for hours and still didn't understand it. Why would that one argument throw an error somewhere else?

Comment: error trace shows that it `only supports NHWC`, which is is a `data_format`, so that's a starting point.